# Google Compute Engine Api using oAuth to list instances c#

Tags: c#, google-compute-engine

Can you please show me some c# example for Authorizing and getting instances using Google Compute engine? When I tried authorizing through some of the code that are out there it is always popping up the gmail login page. Is it necessary to use my own login username or can I use the username of the person who created the vm instances on the google cloud platform?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please show me some c# example for Authorizing and getting instances using Google Compute engine?

The following code can help.

```
private async Task<List<Instance>> GetAllInstances()
{
    List<Instance> instanceResult = new List<Instance>();

    var service = assign GooglecomputeServiceObject;
    InstancesResource instancesResource = new InstancesResource(service);
    InstanceList instanceList = await instancesResource.List(your ProjectId, specify_Zone).ExecuteAsync();

    if (instanceList.Items != null)
        foreach (var item in instanceList.Items)
        {
            instanceResult.Add(item);
        }
    return instanceResult;
}
```